# Compile Error - Variable Required-can't assign to this expression

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

Here's a code I'm replicating:

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
    Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
    Dim Last As Integer:  Last = W.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row
    If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim Symbols As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To Last
        Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("A" & i).Value & "+"
    Next i
    Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols - 1))
    Debug.print Last 
    Debug.print Symbols
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure that the issue is in the third line. I had originally written

```
Dim Last as Integer: Set Last = W.Rang("A100").End(xlUp).Row
```

I realized that `Set` was only for objects and so I removed it. Now I receive the error message:

> Compile Error. Variable Required-cannot assign to this expression.

Any idea on what is wrong?

Comment: Does the code know what `Symbols` is? You have `Symbols=Symbols & ....`  how does the code know what "Symbols" is?

Comment: It does not say Rang. And Sobigen's answer worked. When I print out Symbols to the immediate window it prints out what it's supposed do, which is the information in each cell of the A column plus "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the line:

```
Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols - 1))
```

You're trying to subtract a number from a string.  I think it should be

```
Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)
```

To subtract from the length of `Symbols` When you get a compile error it'll highlight the line that the error is on.  In my case it highlighted the minus sign.

Comment: that was it thanks! For some reason the first line: "Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()" was being highlighted so I had to guess. First time with Excel VBA, don't have the best instincts yet