# VBA Excel defining cell value based on the length of the string (number of characters)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have my coordinates sorted. Unfortunately, some of them feature longer strings, hence it's harder to get around them as you see below.

[image]

The highlighted coordinates are wrong, unfortunately. The error is the derivative of a longer string.

I was trying to find a way to base my code on the string length condition:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-macro-to-count-characters-in-a-cell.1056822/

https://www.exceldome.com/solutions/count-number-of-characters-in-a-cell/

https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/calculate-number-of-words-in-string/

https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-len-function.html

and my code snippet looks as you can see below

```
 With wors
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
SecondLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
 End With

 For Each element In wors.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
   If Len(IsNumeric(element.Value)) < 10 Then
    element.Value = element.Value / 1000000
 Else
 element.Value = element.Value / 10000000
 End If
 Next

 For Each element In wors.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
 If IsNumeric(element.Value) Then
    element.Value = element.Value / 1000000
 End If
 Next
```

I am getting an error:  **Variable required - can't assign to this expression**

[Compile Error - Variable Required-can't assign to this expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327236/compile-error-variable-required-cant-assign-to-this-expression)

How can I define the final cell value based on the total number of characters in the initial string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If Len(IsNumeric(element.Value)) < 10 Then` is the error
You are trying to take the `Len` of a `boolean` which is why the error is thrown.

The following should achieve what you want I think:

```
 For Each element In wors.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
   If IsNumeric(element.Value) Then
     If Len(element.Value) < 10 Then
       element.Value = element.Value / 1000000
     Else
       element.Value = element.Value / 10000000
     End If
   End If
 Next
```

You will also need to do something similar for `column F` because those appear to have the same length-of-data issue